# Django on a Mac

Tags: python, django, macos

I have experience using python, and I want to start learning Django. I recently got a macbook air, and am a complete novice in all things concerning OSx.

I just cannot get Django to run. I have python installed, and have downloaded the Django module and followed the installation instructions from several different places. I am really sorry that I don't have any specific errors or problems - no matter what I try, importing Django never (that is, no module named django can be found).

I am probably overlooking something fairly obvious, or missing some key component that no tutorial bothers to mention because it's so trivial. If you can direct me a place where I can download Django, and maybe go over the basic essentials of installing it, that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are unfortunately no equivalent of MAMP for Python. That being said once you'll get virtualenv setup you won't have any issue at all and be able to manage several projects with different versions of Django easily.

I'm not sure what you've tried but it seems that you've installed Django on the wrong python setup (maybe wrong virtual env?).

There are a few steps:

- Install homebrew
- Install PIP
- Install virtualenv & virtualenvwrapper
- create a vritual env
- install Django in it
- run Django in it

Then you'll work within Python virtual envs and have no problem. Google "homebrew django mac": http://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/ for example.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and I think my problem is with installing PIP. When I install (I did it like this: python get-pip.py) everything works fine, but when I try to continue I get the error: pip: command not found. I'm assuming there's some kind of path setting thats not setup properly?

Comment: Try adding this line at the end of your ~/.bashrc file.

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" 

then run source ~/.bashrc to update your settings